# How to fix incorrect SQLAlchemy metadata after migration

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have defined and created a SQLite database using SQLAlchemy, and added some data. This database has been working fine. However, I made a change to a column name in one the models ("User") and migrated this change using alembic. The current model looks like this, where the old name "analogy" was changed to "metaphor":

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(32), nullable=False, index=True, unique=True)
    registered_on = Column(DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.now())
    metaphor = Column(String(16))
```

The migration seemed to go fine, and I also doublechecked using the SQLite command line to confirm that the schema actually changed.

```
sqlite > .schema
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    username VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
    registered_on DATETIME,  
    metaphor VARCHAR(16), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE (wc_id)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_user_username ON user (username);
CREATE INDEX ix_user_registered_on ON user (registered_on);
```

But now when I try to query the table in Python, I get the following error, referencing the old column name and saying that there is no such column

```
>>> from background.database import db_session
>>> from data.models import User
>>> users = db_session.query(User).all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 509, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: user.analogy

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2843, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2995, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3018, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 948, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 269, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1413, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 265, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 248, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/export/scratch/pt/power/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 509, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: user.goal_period [SQL: 'SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.registered_on AS user_registered_on, user.analogy AS user_analogy \nFROM user'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

After tracing this error, it looks like the name change to the model is not reflected in the metadata imported from SQLAlchemy. So, SQLAlchemy is still using the metadata from the prior version of the table, while the actual database schema and the defined model have a different column name.

I've tried to delete all caches (.pyc, py_cache) to see if that was the source of the problem. 
However, after doing this, there were still no changes to the metadata. 
when I open a new interprer session and query the metadata, it shows the old schema, not the new one.

```
>>> from SQLAlchemy import MetaData
>>> metadata= MetaData()
>>> metadata.tables['user']
Table('user', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', Integer(), table=<user>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('username', String(length=32), table=<user>, nullable=False), Column('registered_on', DateTime(), table=<user>, default=ColumnDefault(datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 5, 12, 33, 57, 11763))), Column('goal_period', String(length=16), table=<user>, default=ColumnDefault('daily'))), schema=None)
```

Why is the metadata is not updated, and how do fix this problem?

Comment: Please include the full traceback. Your metadata code sample seems like it should not produce the printout you've shown, as there is no reflection step.